# Affiliate Link Error with AMP

Tags: wordpress, amp-html

I'm using SEOFrog on Wordpress to show the AMP version of the website. It works great, but there is one little problem, especially for affiliate websites such as Plus500 (with a very strict tracking).

When I'm visiting the AMP version of my website (for example: `google.it/amp/www.mercati24.com/come-funziona-plus500/amp/?client=safari`) and I click on one of the affiliate links of the broker Plus500, such as `plus500.com/it/Marketing/Promotion1.aspx?id=11693&tags=Mercati24Post061213&pl=2` . The affiliation campaign shows an error, because the domain is not `mercati24.com` but `google.it` instead.

I don't think the broker will whitelist `https://www.google.it/amp/www.mercati24.com/`, so is there any way to fix this error by just changing the code on the website?

Thanks in advance,

M

Comment: What kind of error message that you got?

Comment: Basically it says that the link comes from an unauthorized domain (Google.it in this case). The affiliate link click has to come strictly from /mercati24.com/ according to plus500 affiliation rules. So with AMP this is not possible. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Link to non-AMP page which will then redirect to affiliate link.
Referer will be your domain.

Comment: please explain more

Answer (score 0):

AMP pages are cached by Google; in fact - when you create an AMP version of your webpage - *you make Google the owner of that page*. As a result, when a user clicks on a link in an AMP page, the referer is `google.com` instead of your domain. This behaviour makes AMP pages not really suitable for tracking purposes, as they are always served from `google.com`; for such scenario’s (like tracking and affiliate  programs) you need to serve pages from your own domain, not from Google’s AMP cache servers.